# Image upload in Opera 12.17 is broken

Tags: bug, images, opera

Image upload on StackOverflow.com is not working for me:

- Opera 12.17
- Windows 7

The upload dialog opens up, but when I click the "*Drag and drop or click here*" area, nothing happens. Also, if I drop a file, it does not work. A confirmation window is shown, whether I really want to upload my file, but when I chose 'yes', nothing really happens.

Since no file is uploaded, the 'Add picture' button stays deactivated.

The old dialog for image upload worked just fine. Also, in other browsers I can upload. But with my legacy Opera installation I cannot use the built-in upload feature anymore. I have to upload my files to image sharing sites and link them in my post.

Is that just me or can anyone confirm this problem? Is there anything I/we can do about that?

Comment: Opera 12 doesn't seem to be on the supported list of browsers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/158100

Comment: Can you upload an image in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1/sandbox) with Opera 12? Because if that works you can grab the url and paste it in your question/answer. That would be a workaround within Opera....

Comment: In the chat, I can upload images with Opera 12.17. Though, the workaround isn't much better than my current approach. :) Is there any chance this can be fixed, even though Opera 12 is not supported officially? Especially since Opera 12.17 is still the latest release on Linux.

Comment: I wouldn't count on it ...

Comment: 12.17 is not only the latest release for Linux, its the last *real* Opera at all... sad to see this great browser losing more and more compatibility all over the web (which is, on the other hand, understandable since it is getting really old).