# Paste to Imgur in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, images

[Since recently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306935/imgur-copypaste-on-stack-overflow) we have the ability to directly paste an image from the clipboard to Imgur, and to the Stack Overflow proper Imgur widget.

[image: Stack Overflow proper widget]

However, the chat image uploader does not appear to support it. We have the old file/link split dialog.

[image: Stack Overflow proper widget]

Since it appears to be already done from the Imgur side, can we get copypasta in chat too?

Comment: While we're at it, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152863/keep-the-message-id-in-the-text-field-so-i-can-reply-to-a-message-with-an-upload

Comment: While we're at it, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242358/add-support-for-gifv-format-in-chat-onebox

Comment: Do know that the chat uploader is the only work-around for Opera 12 users to upload images, as the new dialog doesn't seem to work in that browser: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305480/image-upload-in-opera-12-17-is-broken#comment243889_305480

Comment: @rene can't opera users just use the regular imgur interface?

Comment: No, because that wouldn't bring their image on the i.stack.imgur.com domain.

Comment: @rene How many people even use Opera 12? That's ancient.

Comment: @bjb568 I know you like to be up to date ... I assume SE has a good view on actual user agents coming in. I only want to make sure they check that before making the final decision...